# Firebase redux data mapstate to props?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux

How to get data from firebase when state is changing ? My mapStateToProps receive the goods data but firebaseConnect just fire only one time ? how to refresh data using the state ?

```
 mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const questions = state.firebase.ordered.questions;
  const page = state.homeReducer.page

 //  console.log(state)
   return {questions,page}
 }  

export default compose(

  firebaseConnect((props, store) => {

  const page = store.getState().homeReducer.page;
  console.log('fire')
    return [
      { type: 'once', path: '/questions' ,queryParams: [ 'limitToFirst='+page ]  }
    ]
  }),

  connect(mapStateToProps),



)
```